# Does pushl "pass to the stack by reference"?

Tags: assembly, stack, cpu-registers

I'm using GAS (AT&T syntax) on Linux, with 32-bit instructions.

As I understand it, when calling a function, the first action of the callee is to copy the value in `%ebp` and place it on top of the stack (and implicitly, to decrement the value of `%esp` by 4 so that it points to this new stack "variable"). This is all accomplished with the instruction `pushl %ebp`.

At this point, both `%ebp` and its stack copy hold garbage. To preserve the stack pointer's current location for later reference, we use `movl %esp, %ebp`. Now the "stack copy" of `%ebp` holds this reference address.

My question: does `%ebp` itself also now hold this address? In the language of C, was `%ebp` "passed" to the stack by reference, or by value? And in general, does modifying the "stack copy" of a register or memory location change the value contained in the original register or memory location?

Comment: Modifying a copy of a register or variable never updates the original.

Comment: By value. `movl %esp, %ebp` does not affect the value saved on the stack, the purpose of that `push` is to save the value so that it can be restored later. Also, this is in no way mandatory, it's just a legacy stack frame that's not typically used in optimized code. Edit: it's mandatory to preserve `ebp` according to standard convention, it is not mandatory to use the standard prologue.

Comment: *"At this point, both `ebp` and its stack copy hold garbage"*. It's pointless stacking a register if it contains a useless value.

Comment: Right, I forgot that movl copies directly to the register. So the value in ebp is used for reference during the function, and then the "garbage" value in the stack copy of ebp is popped back into ebp during the epilogue?

Comment: @Weather Vane That makes sense, I guess the guide I'm reading is just doing it to demonstrate best practice.

Comment: Do not add unrelated tags.

Comment: You only modify the "stack copy" if you pushed the register as a contrivance to reserve space on the stack. OTOH you push `ebp` not because you consider it to "contain garbage" but because `ebp` almost certainly contains data essential for the current process.

Comment: You could think of `%ebp` as "owned" by the caller.  If you're going to modify it by making a stack frame, you need to save/restore it so you don't clobber the caller's `%ebp` when you return.  "Best practice" is to not make a stack frame at all if you don't have to, and treat `%ebp` the same as `%ebx` and other callee-saved registers.  (`-fomit-frame-pointer` is the gcc  default even for 32bit targets.  Debugging / exception-handling still works because the compiler puts stack-frame size info into a table in the `.eh_frame_hdr` section, so be aware of that if you make calls.)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's based on a weird idea of how things work, and will just confuse future readers.  Hopefully the OP got his/her own confusion cleared up, though.